# TwoWay data binding dataGrid and dataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mvvmcross

I have a DataTable which containes some data from a sql database. I want to bind this dataTable to a dataGrid using mvvmcross. Here are my codes :

In **ModelView** :

```
private DataTable _groupeData;
    public DataTable GroupeData
    {
        get { return _groupeData; }
        set
        {
            _groupeData = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => GroupeData);
            Runned++;  //In order to check if the dataTable has updated
            UpdateElementGroupe(EltId, value);  //A method that will update the database using the values in this dataTable
        }

    }
```

In **View** :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GroupeData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

With these codes, I'm able to show dataTable's data in DataGrid, but when I modify a cell in dataGrid, the dataTable doesn't update (as if I had set Mode = OneWay).

Comment: The change would happen *in the data within your table*, so there is no point in checking the setter of the table object instance itself.

Comment: Actually, I need to know when the DataTable is changed, in order to call a method to update the SQL database.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/handling-datatable-events ?

Comment: did you try an ObservableCollection<T> with your model where you define Name and Description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by using an [event handler for the DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/handling-datatable-events), so that when a row is changed, the event handler calls the method which updates the database.

Thanks [grek40](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5265292/grek40) for your help.

On th other hand, using ObservableCellection<T> where T is a class doesn't solve the problem. But if you are using ObservableCellection, I suppose you can handle the event the same way.

Comment: Glad you figured out what you need